# Pure Perl DBI/DBD to query Oracle database

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi, dbd

Is there the possibility of a Pure Perl DBI connection of some kind to an Oracle database? I'm trying to allow for running queries from many different servers of different architectures and avoid worrying about the specific architecture (e.g. Linux or AIX or Solaris), matching the specific installation location for the Perl modules on every server (the location of my HOME directory varies on different servers), the need to install an Oracle Instant Client on every server, and most especially, the need to do a source install of DBI and DBD::Oracle on each server.

I'm imagining something like the following:

- Build and install DBI on a server (with an installed compiler) inside a local::lib environment
- Build and install some kind of pure perl DBD driver (or maybe use one of the built-in DBD drivers?)
- Copy only the directory structure and the .pm files to a target server
- On the target server, run queries against an Oracle database using local::lib to find the modules and DBI_PUREPERL=2 to avoid the need for the .so libraries.

What kind of DBD driver would work in this scenario?  JDBC or ODBC maybe?

Or should I just give up and perform a from-source installation of DBI and DBD::Oracle on sample servers of all the various architectures and then create some kind of installation package of the DBI/DBD modules + Oracle's Instant Client for the each different architecture?  (Bonus points if I can avoid setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to get Oracle's Instant Client to work.)

Thoughts?

Comment: The only (remotely) similar thing that I could think of, is writing the program in Java and using JDBC 'thin' Ora-client (it works without installed Ora-client, unlike JDBC/oci8 or ODBC).